# MYSQL Query - Some results don't return

Tags: mysql

I have a problem im my sql query:

```
SELECT table_2.id, SUM(table_2.time + table_4.time + table_6.time + table_8.time + table_10.time + table_12.time) AS total_time, SUM(table_2.connects + table_4.connects + table_6.connects + table_8.connects + table_10.connects + table_12.connects) AS total_connects FROM table_2
  INNER JOIN table_4 ON table_2.id = table_4.id
  INNER JOIN table_6 ON table_2.id = table_6.id
  INNER JOIN table_8 ON table_2.id = table_8.id
  INNER JOIN table_10 ON table_2.id = table_10.id
  INNER JOIN table_12 ON table_2.id = table_12.id
GROUP BY table_2.authid ORDER BY total_time DESC
```

Ok, I have a script that grabs the user IDS and the time they spent and then puts it in mysql tables depending on which forum they have entered. The query above seems to be working fine but only for the users that have entered all forums, because the others that haven't entered in all forums don't return any result.

The ID is always the same, it is the users ID and connects is the number of times the user enters the specific forum.

If you understand my problem and know the answear please let me know, otherwise I'll try to explain better

Thanks

Comment: Please, do try to explain better. What forums are you talking about? Your table names don't indicate what are they representing

Comment: Hey, use LEFT JOIN for tables/forums that can be not entered.

Comment: what is your expected result if the user id is present in table_8 only?

Comment: Ok, each table represents a Forum. table_2 is a forum, table_4 is another forum etc. Ronnis- basically I just want to do a global stats page with total time and things like that for the same user id. If user id is just present in table_8 his id should return with the time he spent. Anyway, this is already working, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way to do this may be:

```
SELECT id, SUM(time), SUM(connects) 
FROM (
    SELECT id, time, connects FROM table_2
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time, connects FROM table_4
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time, connects FROM table_6
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time, connects FROM table_8
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time, connects FROM table_10
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time, connects FROM table_12
) uniontable
GROUP BY id
```

Since they all have the same fields.

EDIT: And it sounds like it may not be such a strange idea to merge them into one table, especially if you want to count the total time like this ;)

EDIT 2: I'm sorry, that wasn't valid SQL at all. This should be better.

Comment: You were faster :) This solution also works for scenarios where id is present only in for example table_4. Basically a full outer join all :)

Comment: +1: Excellent points all - the only possible issue is that someone who was in none of the forums will not show up with zeroes.  And your solution works even for people that don't visit the forum recorded in table_2, whereas mine does not.

Comment: Is this the best solution? Because I tried this and showed this error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @afonso: redesign your DB to remove the table_N tables and then use the simpler form of this solution that it enables - yes.  And the sub-query needs an `AS x` clause after the close parentheses.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to give the union a name. Try this version.

Comment: Oh yes, this really worked, thanks jonathan leffler and Spiniy Normal and all of you. Now it is working as expected and I learned lot of new things in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the INNER JOIN by a LEFT OUTER JOIN this will get you results over all the tables. You might need to re-define the SUM probably you'll get NULL on users who haven't visited all forums...

Comment: That's right. That's what happened to me.. how do I re-define the sum?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use outer joins and you will need to use IFNULL or something similar to map the "user wasn't in forum" nulls to zeroes.

```
SELECT t2.id,
       SUM(IFNULL(t2.time,      0) + IFNULL(t4.time,      0) +
           IFNULL(t6.time,      0) + IFNULL(t8.time,      0) +
           IFNULL(t10.time,     0) + IFNULL(t12.time,     0)) AS total_time,
       SUM(IFNULL(t2.connects,  0) + IFNULL(t4.connects,  0) +
           IFNULL(t6.connects,  0) + IFNULL(t8.connects,  0) +
           IFNULL(t10.connects, 0) + IFNULL(t12.connects, 0)) AS total_connects
  FROM table_2 AS t2
  LEFT JOIN table_4  AS t4  ON t2.id = t4.id
  LEFT JOIN table_6  AS 76  ON t2.id = t6.id
  LEFT JOIN table_8  AS t8  ON t2.id = t8.id
  LEFT JOIN table_10 AS t10 ON t2.id = t10.id
  LEFT JOIN table_12 AS t12 ON t2.id = t12.id
GROUP BY t2.id ORDER BY total_time DESC
```

This almost works; it does work for all users that visit the forum for which the information is stored in `table_2`.  To make it work for people who don't visit the 'table_2 forum', the query needs to use the table that defines users and do the outer joins with that table:

```
SELECT u.id,
       SUM(IFNULL(t2.time,      0) + IFNULL(t4.time,      0) +
           IFNULL(t6.time,      0) + IFNULL(t8.time,      0) +
           IFNULL(t10.time,     0) + IFNULL(t12.time,     0)) AS total_time,
       SUM(IFNULL(t2.connects,  0) + IFNULL(t4.connects,  0) +
           IFNULL(t6.connects,  0) + IFNULL(t8.connects,  0) +
           IFNULL(t10.connects, 0) + IFNULL(t12.connects, 0)) AS total_connects
  FROM Users         AS u
  LEFT JOIN table_2  AS t2  ON u.id = t2.id
  LEFT JOIN table_4  AS t4  ON u.id = t4.id
  LEFT JOIN table_6  AS 76  ON u.id = t6.id
  LEFT JOIN table_8  AS t8  ON u.id = t8.id
  LEFT JOIN table_10 AS t10 ON u.id = t10.id
  LEFT JOIN table_12 AS t12 ON u.id = t12.id
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY total_time DESC
```

However, given the symmetry of the table_N tables, I think you should do as [Spiny Norman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532314/spiny-norman)
suggests and redesign your schema so that there is one table that stores the timing and connection values:

```
CREATE TABLE ForumUsage
(
    ForumID    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Forums,
    UserID     INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Users,
    Time       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Connects   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Then you sum over the entries in that table.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said sorry

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried your suggestion with IFNULL but if it works, basically it dows the same as COALESCE?

Comment: IFNULL is basically the same as COALESCE; COALESCE has the merit of being in the SQL standard; it has the demerit of being 2 characters longer than IFNULL (and not being listed in the same section of the MySQL manual as IFNULL).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `JOIN` with the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  people.id, SUM(COALESCE(table_2.time, 0) + COALESCE(table_4.time, 0) + table_6.time, 0) + COALESCE(table_8.time, 0) + COALESCE(table_10.time, 0) + COALESCE(table_12.time, 0)) AS total_time,
        SUM(COALESCE(table_2.connects, 0) + COALESCE(table_4.connects, 0) + COALESCE(table_6.connects, 0) + COALESCE(table_8.connects, 0) + COALESCE(table_10.connects, 0) + COALESCE(table_12.connects, 0)) AS total_connects
FROM    people p
LEFT JOIN
        table_2
ON      table_2.id = people.id
LEFT JOIN
        table_4
ON      people.id = table_4.id
LEFT JOIN
        table_6
ON      people.id = table_6.id
LEFT JOIN
        table_8
ON      people.id = table_8.id
LEFT JOIN
        table_10
ON      people.id = table_10.id
LEFT JOIN
        table_12
ON      people.id = table_12.id
GROUP BY
        people.authid
ORDER BY
        total_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

@afonso: I think you should populate all those time tables whenever a new user is created by inserting the user with a time of 0 (just so that they're in the table). Would this be an acceptable compromise for your application just to have those users in the tables so your initial query will work?

Comment: It could be, but I have statistic pages for each forum and one with the global statistics and then in the specific statistic pages there would be much more results than real (I guess I could hide the results which were 0 but anyway I've corrected my problem with all your answers)